# What is causing Semantic-UI-React elements to break my basic Reactjs App?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to React and am trying to utilize Semantic-ui-react. I followed the instructions for installing [React](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage), but am receiving the following error (see links for detailed screenshots, and quote below) in the development console/browser every time I try to add any element from Semantic-ui-react:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

Screenshot of error message on page

[image]

Screenshot of error message in console

[image]

When I `console.log` one of the Semantic-ui-react elements after import, it returns undefined.

Removing the Semantic-ui-react elements, but keeping the JSX resolves the error. I've tried reinstalling both React and Semantic UI React, double checked my imports/exports, and double checked my syntax, but I can't locate the problem.

REPO: https://github.com/LATAEVIA/SS-Artistpage

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
"react": "^16.1.0",
"react-dom": "^16.1.0",
"react-scripts": "1.0.17"
"react-scripts": "1.0.17",
"semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.12",
"semantic-ui-react": "^0.76.0"
```

Index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.min.css"></link>
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import './index.css';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Icon, Header, Container  } from 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
console.log(Button);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ([
      <Container>
        <div key={0}>
          <Header>
            <img alt="Artist Image" />
            <h1>Artist Name</h1>
            <p>
              Artist Bio
            </p>
          </Header>
        </div>,
        <div key={1}>
          <h2>(Artist Name) Songs That Feel Like:</h2>
          <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mood_tags" value="Calm" /> Calm<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mood_tags" value="Mellow" /> Mellow<br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <Button size='small' color='green'>
              <Icon name='download' />
              Download
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Container>
    ]);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace :

```
import { Button, Icon, Header, Container  } from 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

By:

```
import { Button, Icon, Header, Container  } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

Indeed, components cannot be imported from css file .

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!